# Android Number with gradient

Tags: android, styles

[image]

How is it possible to create gradient for dynamic number in Android app?

E.g. TextView or Button with text is used.
(simple solution is a favorite)

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Comment: All answers are good, however @user2247689 solution is more preferable because it shows XML, here is one more helpful example for UI declaration http://stackoverflow.com/a/5300865/304371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
TextView Textview1 = new TextView(this);
Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 20,
        new int[]{Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE},
        new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);
Textview1.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, just create a drawable file, with a gradient:

```
<shape>
            <gradient android:startColor=""
                android:endColor=""
                android:angle=""/>
</shape>
```

and point it in the

```
<TextView ... 
                android:textColor="@drawable/yourdrawablename"/>
```

or programmatically like this :

```
tv.setTextColor(R.drawable.yourdrawablename);
```

Comment: This does not work. Gradient cannot be applied to TextView except programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Shader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.html) and [LinearGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html) in android

```
 TextView textview = new TextView(this);
         Shader shader=   new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0,20,new int[]{Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY},new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.MIRROR);
                        textview.getPaint().setShader(shader);
```